# How can I upsert & populate Lookups with external Id using sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Trying to run the following command on my org using sfdx (Upserting csv into my scratch org) :

```
'sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s Product2 -i ExternalId__c -f data/srv-allproducts.csv -u MyORG '
```

This works fine and do upsert products based on my ExternalId.

=> BUT I have a custom lookup on product which points to My custom Object and I want to populate it with its own ExternalId__c field.

Seems like with this command in DX I only have a way to set ExternalId for the object I'm upserting but don't have a way to map certain lookups to their external unique keys?  Can I add some extra params somehow?

Getting MALFORMED_ID Error when trying.

Comment: Are you following the rules listed [in this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the `-i` parameter in the Salesforce CLI `force:data:bulk:upsert` command.

In your use case, you can use `-i` to identify which field in the `Product2` object the upsert operation will use to determine whether a row of your CSV file will be treated as insert or update. And if update, which record will be updated. In some cases this can be an external ID.

But as you astutely have brought up, external ID has a secondary purpose, which is to perform record matching across relationships and ensure that when a record is inserted the relationship to another object is created.

This is not the purpose of the `-i` flag.

While mapping is widely done and understood, it does not appear to be implemented in the Salesforce CLI currently.

For this reason, all header rows field names must match the Salesforce API name of fields in the object. For upsert with relationships and external Ids, you must use the header row of your CSV to indicate the related external ID field that a value corresponds to. Let's say the value you have is stored in `My_Custom_Object__c.External_Id__c`. Your CSV might look like this:

```
Name, MyCustom_Object__r.External_Id__c, Other_Field__c
Product 1, 12345, Rutabega
Product 2, 98765, Beetroot
```

There are more detailed rules for prepping CSVs in the bulk API developer [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm).